# On click button change step - jquery step

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

So i have this problem with JQuery step, on my first step I disabled the next button to force the user to click on 2 buttons: option 1 or option 2.
When the user click in any of the 2 buttons it will go to the next step (step 2).
But I don't know how to trigger the event to change of step when the user click on any of those buttons. Any idea of what function to use?

Comment: could you post the code you are working with ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this or the actual code upon button click?

```
    $(document).on('click', '.class', function()
    {
        show following step/hide current step?
        clear current html - append next steps html dynamically?
    });
```

It's hard to guess what you want, try being more specific with your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I implemented this today (if you are referring to jQuery steps): What you can do is as follows. (You may not need all of the details, such as the transitionalEffects - it was just what I had in my implementation).

```
$("#steps").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    enableAllSteps: true,
    transitionEffect: "slide",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical",

    onStepChanged: function(event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
    {
        alert('On step changed'); // you can see the step change was picked up
        var current = $("#steps").steps("getCurrentStep"); // get the current step            
        if(current.title == "My Step Two") // see if it matches the name of the step
            alert('Step two was selected');
    }

});
```

Here is what your HTML might look like for the steps:

```
         <div id="steps">
               <h3>My Step One</h3>
                  <section id="stepOne">
                    <!-- step one code -->
                  </section>
               <h3>My Step Two</h3>
                  <section id="stepTwo">
                      <!-- step two code -->
                  </section>
         </div>
```

What this does is listen for an event called `onStepChanged`. From that you can then call a method entitled `getCurrentStep` which returns the entire step object. Then you can ask for the `title` of the step and see if it matches what was in your steps div tag.

Hopefully this will get you what you need.